# Can Identity Server from Abp.io change tenant from URL?

Tags: abp

I have a Identity Server Module running (from Abp.io). I activated multi-tenancy mode and now I have a modal which I can change tenant through it, as images below:[image]

[image: 2]

Ok, my problem is: I want to receive this tenant from a URL parameter instead this modal. I've found **Volo.Abp.AspNetCore.Mvc.UI.MultiTenancy** is the module which is providing this switch; and the class **TenantSwitchModal.cshtml.cs** is where is changing this cookie for us.

So, do I have to overwrite **TenantSwitchModal.cshtml.cs** or is there another way?

I think probably there's a way where I don't need to overwrite anything in Abp core. But I don't know where. Any help?

Comment: Did you manage to figure out a solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

I think what you are looking for is `QueryStringTenantResolveContributor`.

It is one of the default tenant resolver available in ABP and it is enabled by default.

> QueryStringTenantResolveContributor: Tries to find current tenant id
> from query string parameters. The parameter name is __tenant by
> default.

Example Query:

`{URL}/Account/Login?__tenant={yourtenantname}`

Answer (score 1):

if you want to determine current tenant by subdomain (like *mytenant1.mydomain.com*) or by the whole domain (like *mytenant.com*), you can configure the `AbpTenantResolveOptions` to add the domain tenant resolver.

```
Configure<AbpTenantResolveOptions>(options =>
{
    options.AddDomainTenantResolver("{0}.mydomain.com");
});
```

- {0} is the placeholder to determine current tenant's unique name.
- Add this code to the ConfigureServices method of your module.
- This should be done in the Web/API Layer since the URL is a web related stuff.

---

You can also add your own tenant resolver class.

Create your own tenant resolver like below:

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Volo.Abp.MultiTenancy;

namespace MultiTenancyDemo.Web
{
    public class MyCustomTenantResolveContributor : TenantResolveContributorBase
    {
        public override string Name => "Custom";

        public override Task ResolveAsync(ITenantResolveContext context)
        {
            //TODO...
        }
    }
}
```

Configure it in your module class

```
Configure<AbpTenantResolveOptions>(options =>
{
    options.TenantResolvers.Add(new MyCustomTenantResolveContributor());
});
```

---

Further information see https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/Multi-Tenancy