# abp.io Resolve Tenant On Login Screen

Tags: multi-tenant, abp

How can I resolve tenant based on the given credential without using swich tenant section which is available on login screen?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66352719/can-identity-server-from-abp-io-change-tenant-from-url

Comment: Ok, I read this but in my case user will click on on the login menu link and user will be redirected to login screen. At that time I can not determine who the user is and url have no parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is not applicable since you enable MultiTenant Option and you don't use additional unique key for tenants,

Because in case of enabling Multitenant, the user Identification based on Username and TenantId , as you can find in your DB 2 users with same username and different TenantId, so your system will not be able to identify the targeted user using username only.

In your case you can implement this identification using other ways

- Identify the targeted tenant using the domain or subdomain check the documentation here https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/Multi-Tenancy
- Another option is identify the tenant from the second part of user email, for example username@tenant1 , username@tenant2 , this is applicable if you restricted your users to register using specific tenants domains